# about generate maven dependency

Tags: maven

I am pretty new to maven.
Now I have a maven project developed. My another project needs to depend on this one.
Does anyone know how can I generate my own dependency? So that my second project can add the first one as a dependency in pom.
thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Since your first project is already a maven-project, just install it in your local repository by running `mvn install` in the first project's root directory.

Then you can include a dependency in your second project by simply referencing the groupId, artifactId and version you defined in the first project.

So if your first project had the following in its pom:

```
    <project>
        <groupId>com.yourdomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>yourcomponent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    ... <!-- more here -->
```

you can include this in your second project:

```
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yourdomain</groupId>
            <artifactId>yourcomponent</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Unless you deploy your project 1 jar to a central maven repository, this will only work if your jar is in your local repository (via mvn install).

Answer (score 1):

Maven projects are identified by the "Maven coordinates", that is, the ArtifactID, GroupID and version.

Say you create your first project and run `maven install`. Your local repository (in $HOME/.m2/) will now contain the compiled project plus whatever coordinates you put in there.

Your second project must now only depend on the said coordinates.

I would suggest googling a bit on maven. I made a tutorial a long time ago that might help you, even if the examples are a little simple. [Here you go](https://github.com/miquelmartin/Dive-into-Maven-Tutorial) and good luck!